# JQuery Toggle not working in responsive layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I reckon this will turn out to be a simple error, but it's driving me round the bend. I have a JQuery Toggle function to hide/show a DIV navigation. I'm using the following code to create the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function toggleDiv(divId) {
                $("#" + divId).toggle();
            }
</script>
```

And the following to call it:

```
<div class="jumpMenu">
        <a class="jump" href="javascript:toggleDiv('menuColumn');">
        <div class="arrow-down"></div>
        Portal menu
        </a>
</div>
```

The declaration of the div I'm referencing is:

```
<div class="esitLeft hidePrint off" runat="server" id="menuColumn" style="display: block;">
```

Is there anything not quite right there?

Comment: i tried your code here, itz working fine ?
http://jsfiddle.net/kFrng/

Comment: Are you missing a reference to jQuery in your page?